# Java serializing fields that not implementing `Serializable`

Tags: java

I've read several related questions, but none is of the smilier situation.

Here is my question, suppose I have a class

```java
class A implements Serializable {
    private int a;
    private B   b;
}

class B {
    private int c;
    public int  getC() {...};
    public void setC() {...};
}
```

Here, I have class `A` implemented by myself, so I can make it `Serializable` and do whatever I want, while class `B` is provided in another library, for which I cannot, and even I can, I do not want to modify it directly.

The goal is to serialize all fields in `A`, e.g., `int a` and `B b`. How should I implement `writeObject` and `readObject` in this case?

Comment: Are you forced to serialize using binary serialization usually meant with `Serializable` or can you come up with your own format?

Comment: What kind of serialization you need to do? Is it binary/JSON/XML?

Comment: add new `Class C extends B implements Serializable ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 special methods to manually serialize it:

- private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os)
- private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is)

With them you can manually write and read it, making it transient in another Class:

```
    private transient B b;
```

One example:

```
class A implements Serializable {
  private int a;
  private transient B b;

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
  try {
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeInt(b.getC()); // one its example property to write
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) {
  try {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    b = new B(is.readInt()); // the new istance with one example property to read
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}
}
```